# Statements outside for loop are not being executed

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, unreachable-code

I'm new to Java. I found a website called project eulder and was practicing on a problem.
I don't understand why the following program does not display anything but when I put System.out.println(max); into the for loop it works but displaying all the prime numbers including the biggest. Who do I only the display the biggest prime number?

```
public class LargestPrimeFactor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long x = 600851475143L;
        int max = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
            if (x % i == 0)
                if (isPrime(i))
                    max = i;
        }
        System.out.println(max);

    }

    public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
        for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should learn to use a debugger. Failing that, you should write out each step your algorithm takes.

Comment: It is called `LargestPrimeFactor`, not `AllThePrimeFactors`

Comment: You are going to overflow the int in the loop.

Comment: You know, if you start at the top and go down, you'll find *only* the largest, without having to first check all of the trillion numbers below it.

Comment: Logically, your code is correct (put a System.out.println after isPrime(i) - and please add more braces - and you'll see your code working). You're just not giving it enough time to get through 600851475143 values. Which means you may want to re-think your approach.

Comment: Another optimization you can make, in your `isPrime()` method you can check if `n` is divisible by 2, then only check odd factors up to the square root of `n`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have written an infinite loop: `600851475143L` is greater than the maximum value that can be stored in an `int`, so `i <= x` will always be `true`.

Changing `i` and all the other relevant variables to `long` may solve this issue, but you'll still have to rethink your algorithm. Checking if 600851475143 numbers are prime is just going to take too long.

**Hint:** once you have found a number that divides `x`, you can divide `x` by that number... (Hope this doesn't spoil the fun)

Comment: How *do* you do a for-loop when the number is too big for an `int`? Not that he should, I just want to know.

Comment: Simple: `for (long l=0; l < max; l++) ...` Nothing in the for loop syntax forces you to use `int`, or even numbers.

Comment: Thank you! Changing all the variables to long did not solve the issue as it took too much time to find the number but dividing x by its divisor directly gave me the answer